# Incoming calls not working while outgoing are OK

Tags: nokia-lumia-525, calls

My Nokia Lumia 525 suddenly stopped accepting incoming calls. Outgoing calls are OK.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your phone or reseating the SIM card?